# Get text property of all forms in an assembly via reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm trying to iterate over all assemblies in my solution, get all forms and retrieve the text property of each form but I don't really know how to get the value. Here is my code:

```
 Type formType = typeof(Form);

 var assemblies =
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

 foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
 {
    var types = assembly.GetTypes();

    foreach (var type in types)
    {
       if (formType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
       {
          var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == "Text");
       }
    }
 }
```

I'm not able to retrieve the concrete value of the form text property. I also
tried

```
var property = type.GetProperty("Text").GetValue(???, null);
```

but don't know how to get the current class. Any ideas? Thank you!

EDIT: i also tried

```
var frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type)
```

but if the form has no parameterless constructor this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to iterate over `Application.OpenForms` collection. This will get you all opened forms owned by the application.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't need open forms. I need all forms that are in my solution and get the Text property which displays ther forms name

Comment: Then you have to go with @sulo 's suggestion and use (for example) some sort of static reference list where you keep all your form instances.

Comment: But why? I Need to write a test where I go over all forms in my solution and read their .Text property. This will be matched against a regex later to check if the text of the form was set correctly.

Comment: To access the Text property you need to create an instance of the class. No instance --> no Text property. So if you're writing test cases you were on the right track by using `Activator.CreateInstance`. If you don't want to or can't create parameterless constructors you can try `Activator.CreateInstance(Type, Object[])` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wcxyzt4d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: But even when I create an instance I can't get the value of the Text property.

Comment: I don't get it. If you can create an instance, why can't you access the `Text` property?

Comment: I can't create instances if the constructor takes parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you need only references to open forms, you can use [`Application.OpenForms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx).
Otherwise you need to have some list of all form references.